# How to simulate data for ordinal cumulative probit/logit model with random effect?

Tags: simulation

I am currently working on a project to improve the knowledge score on certain disease. The outcome variable is ordinal with 8 levels. In order to estimate the sample size, I need to run a simulation. I need help how to put random effects on individuals in my simulation?

Comment: Ok, maybe you could describe the simulation you want to do a little more precise using model equations and perhaps code you already have and let the people know exactly where it is you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got some data already? If so, you can generate random subsets of it, of various sizes. 
If not, then you need to make some assumption about the distribution of scores.